# Why doesn't lead converted date match to anything?

Tags: reporting, leads, lead-conversion

I'm creating some reports from SalesForce in a standalone reporting tool, I'm looking at how long it takes for a lead to be converted to an account and then for an opportunity to be attached.

I thought that the lead conversion date would give me something to work with, that when a lead is converted the account is created however this doesn't seem to be the case.

Can someone explain when the lead conversion date is captured and why this date is different to when account is created?

[image: Lead figures]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge leads in to *existing* accounts, which is why the converted date may not match the created date. You might want to start by going to the Leads home tab and choosing the "Lead Lifetime" report in the lower-left side.

Comment: Ahh I see, so if creating a new account they will match?

Comment: @ChrisJ Yes, I also just made a note about the Lead Lifetime report, which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: perfect, just ran this and it's making sense to me now